# A pop to select environment texture doesn't come up

Tags: texturing, color, properties, hdri, world

[image]

When I click the circle next to color swatch under world property, a pop up is meant to appear so I can select environment texture, but nothing appears.[image]

Comment: Please [take a screenshot](https://www.take-a-screenshot.org/windows.html) and [edit your question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/206644/edit) using the [built in tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jrOpa.jpg).

Comment: To make screenshots use Window > Save Screen Shot from the top menu. Photos from phones are hard to see.

Comment: To select the texture click on the color and instead of color use an environment texture. Or open the Shade Editor window and add the nodes there.

Comment: Added a visible screenshot

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are on cycles engine [image]
and click the circle right beside color instead. it took me foreverrrrrr with this problem. [image]

Comment: It's not specific to Cycles.

Answer (score 0):

The popup to add an input node to a property is shown by clicking the button on the left side of the input:

[image]

The button on the right side is key/un-key the property for animation:

[image]

This is why your screenshot shows the right-side button as a big diamond and the property bordered in yellow: you just added a keyframe:

[image]

---

For shaders that use nodes, you can also use the Shader Editor instead of the properties Editor.

Since it's a world shader, you need to switch your Shader Editor to World:

[image]

Then you can hit <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> to add a new node from the nodes list and then plug it to the inputs you want, or drag and drop a node to open the nodes list to create and connect a node to that input.

[image]